# Show that this pairing function is onto N

Tags: arithmetic, natural-numbers

Trying to show that the function $f: \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(m,n) = 2^m (2n+1) - 1$ is surjective. Easy to show that any even $k \in \mathbb{N}$ can be mapped to by taking $(m,n) = (0, k/2)$. Not so sure about odd $k$, even by induction. Would appreciate any pointers.

Edit: I should add, without using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, only in fairly introductory set theoretic terms (say level of Jech, chapter on finite sets).

Comment: It seems to me, you can't generate $3$ this way. Maybe something is not good.

Comment: @guest Note that $f(2,0)=3$. I think everything is fine. Perhaps, the confusion stems from the fact that some mathematicians use $\Bbb{N}$ to denote the non-negative integers, while other mathematicians use $\Bbb{N}$ to denote the positive integers.

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard , yes, I missed that $n$ can be zero

Comment: $k+1$ can be uniquely represented as $2^m(2n+1)$. Namely, $2^m$ (with $m\geqslant0$) is the largest power of $2$ dividing $k+1$, while $2n+1$ (with $n\geqslant0$) is the largest odd number dividing $k+1$.

Answer (score 3):

If $k\in\mathbb N$, then let $2^m$ be the highest power of $2$ that divides $k+1$. Then $\frac{k+1}{2^m}$ is odd; in other words, it is of the form $2n+1$. Therefore, $f(m,n)=k$.

Comment: is there a way to show this without assuming the unique representation in terms of a product of odd and even numbers and no sophisticated theorem of arithmetic? ideally using straightforward induction

Answer (score 2):

For odd $k$, you have

$$2^m(2n + 1) - 1 = k \implies 2^m(2n + 1) = k + 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note $k + 1$ is even, so it has a highest power of $2$ divisor, call it $m$, as well as an odd factor. Have this odd factor be $2n + 1$ for some $n \ge 0$. Note this only works properly if you assume that $0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: is there a way to show this without assuming the unique representation in terms of a product of odd and even numbers and no sophisticated theorem of arithmetic? ideally using straightforward induction

Comment: @boomerharvest Unfortunately, note the corresponding values of $m$ and $n$ can jump around a lot, with no apparent connection between them, as you increment $k$ by $2$ each time, so I don't see any way offhand how to prove this using "straightforward induction", . Nonetheless, although I'm leaving in a few minutes, I will think about this issue and, later today, review this again to see if anything comes to mind.

Comment: Right. Thanks. I'm asking because in their set theory textbook, Jech & Hrbacek leave it to the reader to show that this function is a bijection between N^2 and N as part of a proof on cardinality. Given that the results available in the chapter thus far are pretty standard I was assuming there is a more straightforward way about it.

Answer (score 0):

The same idea, but a bit different angle:

every natural number $k+1$ can be written in a binary system.
For example, let $k+1 = 1101\dots0100$, which means 
$$
k+1 = 1\times 2^n + 1\times 2^{n-1} + 0\times 2^{n-2} + \cdots + 0.
$$
Let's remove all zeroes from consideration, i.e. let $\alpha_1>\alpha_2>\dots$ and $$
k+1 = 2^{\alpha_1} + 2^{\alpha_2} + \dots + 2^{\alpha_s}.
$$
Note that all $\alpha$ differ at least by $1$.
Now write the last equality as
$$
k+1 = 2^{\alpha_s} \left(
      2 \underbrace{\left(
         2^{\alpha_1-\alpha_s-1}+\dots+2^{\alpha_{s-1}-\alpha_{s}-1}
        \right)}_{n} + 1
      \right).
$$
Interestingly
$$
2^{\alpha_s + 1} - 1 = k \text{ xor } (k+1).
$$